# true false quiz controlling dive to be visible or hidden

Tags: javascript

on one page I have

```
    <div class="quiz-question" id="q1"><strong>This is the question?</strong></div>
<div class="quiz-choices">
    <div class="quiz_choice"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1T" value="T"><label for="q1T">True</label></div>
    <div class="quiz_choice"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1F" value="F"> <label for="q1F">False</label></div> 
</div>
```

Then on the final page I have

```
    <div class="quiz-question" id="q1"><strong>This is the question?</strong></div>
<div class="quiz-correct">
    <div class="quiz-answer-correct"><strong><strong>You answered:</strong></strong> <span class="quiz-answer">TRUE</span></div>
    <div class="quiz-answer"><strong><strong>The correct answer is:</strong></strong> TRUE</div>
</div>
<div class="quiz-wrong">
    <div class="quiz-answer-wrong"><strong>You answered:</strong> FALSE</div>
    <div class="quiz-answer"><strong>The correct answer is:</strong> TRUE</div>
</div>
```

The answer is showing up in the address bar, but I don't know how to translate it into the site. Usually I would use php and make it an if than situation. But it has to be html, so I imagine I need to use javascript. In the address bar it is showing up ...quiz.html/?q1=T&q2=F&q3=F

Comment: This link should tell you all you need to know to do this: http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

Comment: What are actually trying to do? your question it is not really clear. In the other hand, `if/then/else` is almost the same in every language.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem having to make a website strictly in .html rather than php and I wondered how to do some things that I knew how to do in php but not in javascript. I like the answer provided by jmiraglia.

In addition, if you don't want to use javascript, there's one cool and fast way is to use .htaccess file to help you run php code even though your file is in .html extension.

The way to do it is to use your text editor to create a file without a name but just an extension of .htaccess, save it and put it in the same directory where you have your .html file.

Inside the .htaccess file, put a block of code like this:

```
<Files TheNameofthePageWhereYouWanttorunPHPcode.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
</Files>
```

and save it.

Then you are free to use your php code in the .html file you specify in the code above. Such as using the $_GET to get the answer from the address bar like this:

```
<?php $ans1 = $_GET['q1']; 
echo $ans1;
?>
```

and use your if statement to show it where you want it to.

Some server already has one .htaccess and it might be hidden and some servers allow you to use it some don't. If you don't see one in the directory you can create one yourself and test it. You can look it up on the articles on the internet on how to use .htaccess to run php code in .html file such as this one. http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/php-in-html-files.html and https://www.rssinclude.com/blog/36_how_to_run_php_scripts_in_html_or_htm_files .It works for me.